# how to get the array of affected rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am passing user_id and video_id to delete the events stored in the database but i need the e_id which is event id those are deleted in the form of array after performing the DELETE query, any suggestion is helpful.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    require('config.inc.php');
    
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $video_id = $_REQUEST['video_id'];
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT e_id, video_id FROM schedule WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $st->bindValue(":user_id",$user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->execute();
    $str = "";
    while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $video_ids = explode(",", $row["video_id"]);
        print_r($video_ids);
        if(in_array($video_id, $video_ids)) {
            $st2 = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM schedule WHERE e_id = :e_id ");
            $st2->bindValue(":e_id", $row["e_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $st2->execute();
            $str .= $row["e_id"];
        } else {
            echo "含まれていない";
        }
    }
    echo "$str";
    $sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM download_video WHERE user_id = :user_id AND video_id = :video_id ");
    $sth->bindValue(":user_id",$user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(":video_id",$video_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
?>
```

Comment: To get affected rows use `$count = $sth->rowCount(); echo "Deleted".$count;` read here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#affected

Comment: Hi Dlk thanks for the response, i actually need the list of affected rows e_id's in array

Comment: Add them into array then?